# Policy JSON gets lost (MalformedPolicyDocument: Policy statement must contain resources)

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

### My Goal

I am trying to download a specific version (later itll be the latest version) of a IAM Policy for AWS-Load-Balancer-Controller at runtime in Terraform. Then use that downloaded JSON policy as a source document for my final policy document, that includes some constraints for security purposes.

### What should be happening

1. The policy should be downloaded by my `data.http.policy` object
2. The final policy doc should reference the `data.http.policy.response_body` as a source doc, and add some additional details. (Some conditions for security)
3. The IAM Policy Resource should reference the `data.aws_iam_policy_document.aws_load_balancer_controller` for the Policy JSON

### Error

`creating IAM Policy aws-load-balancer-controller: MalformedPolicyDocument: Policy statement must contain resources.`
Somehow, somewhere the value I generated is getting lost... Any thoughts or ideas would be appreciated here.

```
locals {
  policy = data.aws_partition.current.partition == "aws-us-gov" ? "iam_policy_us-gov" : "iam_policy"
  version = "2.5.1"
}

data "http" "policy" {
  url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-load-balancer-controller/v${local.version}/docs/install/${local.policy}.json"
}

# What can this do?
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "aws_load_balancer_controller" {
  source_policy_documents = [data.http.policy.response_body]

  statement {
    effect = "Allow"
    actions = [
      "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress",
      "ec2:RevokeSecurityGroupIngress"
    ]

    condition {
      test     = "ArnEquals"
      variable = "ec2:Vpc"
      values   = ["arn:${data.aws_partition.current.partition}:ec2:${var.region}:${data.aws_caller_identity.me.id}:vpc/${var.vpc_id}"]
    }

    condition {
      test     = "Null"
      variable = "aws:ResourceTag/kubernetes.io/cluster/${var.cluster}"
      values   = ["false"]
    }
  }
  depends_on = [
    data.http.policy
  ]
}

# Make the "Permissions" into a Policy
resource "aws_iam_policy" "aws_load_balancer_controller" {
  count = var.chart.name == "aws-load-balancer-controller" ? 1 : 0

  name        = var.chart.name
  path        = "/"
  description = "Policy for enabling access by ${var.chart.name}"

  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.aws_load_balancer_controller.json

  depends_on = [
    data.aws_iam_policy_document.aws_load_balancer_controller
  ]
}
```

#### Solution (Credit to @luk2302)

```
locals {
  policy = data.aws_partition.current.partition == "aws-us-gov" ? "iam_policy_us-gov" : "iam_policy"
  version = "2.5.1"
}

data "http" "policy" {
  url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-load-balancer-controller/v${local.version}/docs/install/${local.policy}.json"
}

# What can this do?
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "aws_load_balancer_controller" {
  source_policy_documents = [data.http.policy.response_body]

  statement {
    effect = "Allow"
    actions = [
      "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress",
      "ec2:RevokeSecurityGroupIngress"
    ]
    resources = ["*"]


    condition {
      test     = "ArnEquals"
      variable = "ec2:Vpc"
      values   = ["arn:${data.aws_partition.current.partition}:ec2:${var.region}:${data.aws_caller_identity.me.id}:vpc/${var.vpc_id}"]
    }

    condition {
      test     = "Null"
      variable = "aws:ResourceTag/kubernetes.io/cluster/${var.cluster}"
      values   = ["false"]
    }
  }
  depends_on = [
    data.http.policy
  ]
}

# Make the "Permissions" into a Policy
resource "aws_iam_policy" "aws_load_balancer_controller" {
  count = var.chart.name == "aws-load-balancer-controller" ? 1 : 0

  name        = var.chart.name
  path        = "/"
  description = "Policy for enabling access by ${var.chart.name}"

  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.aws_load_balancer_controller.json

  depends_on = [
    data.aws_iam_policy_document.aws_load_balancer_controller
  ]
}
```

Comment: Nothing is lost here, it is just that the statement you have written does not reference any resources which makes no sense.

Comment: uggh I hate/love when its something so freaking simple. 
That fixed it, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Credit to @luk2302

This was a very simple error, I was just an idiot this morning :face-palm:
The `aws_iam_policy_document` just needed some resources in the statement, so I added `resources = ["*"]`, and it works now.

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "aws_load_balancer_controller" {
  source_policy_documents = [data.http.policy.response_body]

  statement {
    effect = "Allow"
    actions = [
      "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress",
      "ec2:RevokeSecurityGroupIngress"
    ]
    resources = ["*"]


    condition {
      test     = "ArnEquals"
      variable = "ec2:Vpc"
      values   = ["arn:${data.aws_partition.current.partition}:ec2:${var.region}:${data.aws_caller_identity.me.id}:vpc/${var.vpc_id}"]
    }

    condition {
      test     = "Null"
      variable = "aws:ResourceTag/kubernetes.io/cluster/${var.cluster}"
      values   = ["false"]
    }
  }
  depends_on = [
    data.http.policy
  ]
}
```